# Some problems with for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

**EDIT question to make it *understandable***.
Today I tried to do a programm analize a html file, but I had some problems. 
When I debug my project it crashes, and doesn't respond to my commands. There are my split code:

```
    string Riga = "<html> <head> </head> <body> </body> </html>";
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
         for (int j = i + 1; Riga[j - 1] != '>'; j++)
         {
              c++;
              //My code
         }
    }

    for (int i = 0; Riga[i] < Riga.Count(); i++)
    {
         //My code
    }
```

I think that the problem are in the for-loops, but I'm not sure. So can someone explain to me what's wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why was this tagged with [tag:java] and [tag:vb]?

Comment: Nice effort, but what is your question? Also looking at your code it looks like you are trying to parse HTML manually instead of using an HTML parser such as Html Agility Pack which is kind of wrong.

Comment: What stack trace do you get when the program crashes? Have you tried isolating the problem? Also, your code has ten levels of loop and if..else nesting, that makes it nearly impossible to reason about without a test case to step through in a debugger.

Comment: Also: what is this code supposed to *do* with the HTML it's processing?

Comment: I presume you're using windows forms?

Comment: Have you tried refactoring the two lines I pointed out?  It sounds like you're making an infinite loop, and both of those lines are good candidates for where.

Comment: @Fuex What's the stacktrace of the crash? The code excerpt doesn't have any obvious crash reason like a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you open the possibility for an infinite loop here:

```
for (int j = i + 1; Riga[j - 1] != '>'; j++)
```

EDIT: also, what's about this line?

```
for (int i = 0; Riga[i] < Riga.Count(); i++)
```

Why are you comparing the character to the length of the line?  Shouldn't it be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Riga.Count(); i++)
```

?

Comment: Glad you found the problem!  Just remember what I said about tags sometimes splitting over multiple lines, don't assume that any line is an atomic unit.